# How to call a asp.net page asynchronously using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to call a aspx page method asynchronously using JQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX in jQuery to call a page method without too much trouble.  Though I guess it depends on what you're trying to do.  Sometimes it's better to contain your asynchronous methods inside a web service or web handler instead of the page.

[I've posted on how to do this here](http://oddiandeveloper.blogspot.com/2009/07/asynchronous-posting-with-aspnet-jquery.html).  But it's not an example on how to do it with a page method, though the process is very similar.

BTW, a quick web search will turn up MANY results on what you're trying to do.

[This example is very good.](http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx)